# how do I find opengl version from headers GL/gl.h

Tags: opengl

I know to get opengl version on Linux using glxinfo. What I need to get is opengl version number from its headers.

Inside GL/gl.h I have these defines. How do I get the numeric version number from these?

```
#define GL_VENDOR               0x1F00
#define GL_RENDERER             0x1F01
#define GL_VERSION              0x1F02
#define GL_EXTENSIONS               0x1F03
```

Comment: They already are numeric! Just in hexa-decimal.

Comment: @renemilk: These constants are not the version itself, they are for use as input parameters to the [glGetString](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/glGetString.xml) function. I don't think it's possible to get the OpenGL version just from the header file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is valid for core profiles :

```
int major = 0;
int minor = 0;
glGetIntegerv(GL_MAJOR_VERSION, &major);
glGetIntegerv(GL_MINOR_VERSION, &minor);
```

In "old" 1.1 OpenGL you can only get the version string with

```
glGetString(GL_VERSION)
```

But this is a string and you'll need to manually parse it.

Comment: Just as a side-note: Calling `glGetIntegerv` already requires a valid OpenGL context.

Answer (score 4):

> I know to get opengl version on linux using glxinfo. What I need to get is opengl version number from its headers.

It doesn't work that way. The OpenGL version available is a runtime variable and is not known at compile time. You have to query it using `glGet…`